# VecUtil: take nth element of processed vector by two slightly different way

Tags: coq

I want to prove `trivial_request` and think we need `request_eq` to prove `trivial_request`.

```
Lemma request_eq : forall (n k:nat)(a b:Euc (S n))(H:(S k < S n)%nat),
Vnth (request (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil a b) H =
Vnth (request (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil (Vtail a) (Vtail b)) (lt_S_n H).
Proof.
destruct n; intros.
inversion H; inversion H1.
suff main : (forall (k m n:nat)(v1 v2:Euc (S (S m)))(v3:Euc (S (S n)))(H3:((S k) < (S (S n)))%nat),
(k <= (S n) <= (S m))%nat ->
Vnth (updateRnA (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil v1 v2 v3) H3 =
Vnth (updateRnA (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil (Vtail v1) (Vtail v2) (Vtail v3)) (lt_S_n H3)).
have [klen | ngtk] := (Compare_dec.le_lt_dec k (S n)).
rewrite (main k n n a b); intuition.
have : (k < S n)%nat; lia.
induction k0; intros.
VSntac v3; VSntac (Vtail v3); rewrite /=.
rewrite 2!Derive_deriveA_id 2!Vnth_tail.
rewrite (Vnth_eq v1 (kLess (S m) (n0 - 0)) (lt_n_S (kLess m (n0 - 0)))); try lia.
rewrite (Vnth_eq v2 (kLess (S m) (n0 - 0)) (lt_n_S (kLess m (n0 - 0)))) //; try lia.
have : ((S k0) < S (S n0))%nat. move: H3; lia. move => H4.
have : (k0 <= S n0 <= S m)%nat. lia. move => H5.
move: (IHk0 m n0 v1 v2 v3 H4 H5) => H6.
Abort.

Lemma trivial_request : forall (k A:nat)(a b:Euc A)(H:(k < A)%nat),
   Vnth (request (fun p:Euc 0 => id) Vnil a b) H = 
   Vnth a H - deriveA (fun p:Euc 0 => id) Vnil a b H.
Proof.
induction k; intros; destruct a.
inversion H.
rewrite /= 2!Derive_deriveA_id.
rewrite (Vnth_eq b (kLess n (n - 0)) H);last first. lia.
rewrite (Vnth_eq (Vcons h a) (kLess n (n - 0)) H) => //; lia.
inversion H.
rewrite Derive_deriveA_id.
VSntac b.
move: (IHk n a (Vtail b) (lt_S_n H)) => IHk2.
rewrite Derive_deriveA_id in IHk2.
rewrite request_eq /=.
apply IHk2.
Qed.
```

`request` updates elements of vector with gradient of an arbitrary function on its element. `deriveA` return gradients on each elements.

I must limit value of `k` and `A` more over 1 to pass two vectors to `Vtail`. Induction on A may be useless because size of vector is limitted more over 1. But, I don't know other usefull way.

I only need to prove `trivial_request`, so if there is a better way, please let me know. Please tell me your solution.

```
Require Import Psatz.
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.
Require Import CoLoR.Util.Vector.VecUtil.
Require Import Coquelicot.Coquelicot.
Require Import Coq.Init.Datatypes.

Definition Euc (n:nat) := vector R n.
Definition EucSum {A}(e:Euc A) :R:= Vfold_right Rplus e 0.
Definition QE (r1 r2:R):R:= (/ 2)*((r1 - r2)^2).
Definition QuadraticError {n : nat} (v1 v2: Euc n) :Euc n:= Vmap2 QE v1 v2.

Definition kLess (P k:nat): (P - k < (S P))%nat.
lia. Defined.

Definition deriveA {P A B}(I:Euc P -> Euc A -> Euc B)
                          (p :Euc P)(input:Euc A)(train:Euc B){k:nat}(H:(k < A)%nat):R:=
Derive (fun x => EucSum (QuadraticError (I p (@Vreplace R A input k H x)) train))
                                                            (@Vnth R A input k H).

Definition updateRnA {P A B} :(Euc P -> Euc (S A) -> Euc B) ->
                               Euc P -> Euc (S A) -> Euc B -> forall {n:nat}, Euc n -> Euc n:=
fun I p input train => fix fr {n} v:=
    match v with
    |Vnil => Vnil
    |Vcons x _ xs => Vcons (x - (deriveA I p input train (kLess A (n-1)))) (fr xs)
    end.

Definition request {P A B} :(Euc P -> Euc A -> Euc B) -> Euc P -> Euc A -> Euc B -> Euc A.
 refine (match A with
           | O => fun _ _ _ _ => Vnil
           | S A' => _
           end);
 intros I p input train;
 exact (updateRnA I p input train input).
Defined.
```

We may need `Derive_deriveA_id` to prove `request_eq`.

```
Lemma ex_deriveA_id k : forall (n:nat)(a b: Euc n)(H:(k < n)%nat),
ex_derive (fun x : R => EucSum (QuadraticError (id (Vreplace a H x)) b)) (Vnth a H).
Proof.
induction k; intros; destruct a; rewrite /EucSum/=/QE.
inversion H.
apply (ex_derive_plus _ _ _ (ex_derive_scal _ _ _ (ex_derive_pow _ _ _
                           (ex_derive_minus _ _ _ (ex_derive_id _) (ex_derive_const _ _))))
                                                                   (ex_derive_const _ _)).
inversion H.
rewrite /EucSum/= in IHk.
apply (ex_derive_plus _ _ _ (ex_derive_const _ _) (IHk n a (Vtail b) (lt_S_n H))).
Qed.

Lemma Derive_deriveA_id k : forall (n:nat)(a b: Euc n)(H:(k < n)%nat),
(deriveA (fun p:Euc 0 => id) Vnil a b H) = Vnth a H - Vnth b H.
Proof.
induction k; intros; destruct a; rewrite /deriveA/EucSum/=.
inversion H.
rewrite /=/QE;
rewrite (Derive_plus _ _ _ (ex_derive_scal _ _ _ (ex_derive_pow _ _ _
                           (ex_derive_minus _ _ _ (ex_derive_id _) (ex_derive_const _ _))))
                                                                   (ex_derive_const _ _))
(Derive_const _ _) Derive_scal
(Derive_pow _ _ _ (ex_derive_minus _ _ _ (ex_derive_id _) (ex_derive_const _ _)))
(Derive_minus _ _ _ (ex_derive_id _) (ex_derive_const _ _)) Derive_id (Derive_const _ _)
/= Rplus_comm Rplus_0_l Rminus_0_r -Rmult_assoc 2!Rmult_1_r Rinv_l; auto; rewrite Rmult_1_l
(Vnth_eq b H (Nat.lt_0_succ n)); auto; rewrite -Vhead_nth //.
inversion H.
rewrite /deriveA/EucSum/id in IHk.
rewrite (Derive_plus _ _ _ (ex_derive_const _ _) (ex_deriveA_id k n a (Vtail b) (lt_S_n H)))
        (Derive_const _ _) /EucSum/id Rplus_comm Rplus_0_r
        (IHk n a (Vtail b) (lt_S_n H)) -(Vnth_eq b (lt_n_S (lt_S_n H)) H (eq_refl (S k)))
        (Vnth_tail b (lt_S_n H)) //.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it on my own.

```
Lemma updateRnA_tail : forall (k n m:nat)(v1 v2:Euc (S m))(v3:Euc (S n))(H3:((S k) < (S n))%nat),
(k <= (S n) <= (S m))%nat ->
Vnth (updateRnA (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil v1 v2 v3) H3 =
Vnth (updateRnA (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil v1 v2 (Vtail v3)) (lt_S_n H3).
Proof.
induction k; intros; destruct n.
inversion H3; try lia.
VSntac v3; rewrite /=//.
inversion H3; try lia.
VSntac v3; rewrite /=//.
Qed.

Lemma request_eq : forall (n k:nat)(a b:Euc (S n))(H:(S k < S n)%nat),
Vnth (request (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil a b) H =
Vnth (request (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil (Vtail a) (Vtail b)) (lt_S_n H).
Proof.
destruct n; intros.
inversion H; inversion H1.
suff main : (forall (k n m:nat)(v1 v2:Euc (S (S m)))(v3:Euc (S (S n)))(H3:((S k) < (S (S n)))%nat),
(k <= (S n) <= (S m))%nat ->
Vnth (updateRnA (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil v1 v2 v3) H3 =
Vnth (updateRnA (λ _ : Euc 0, id) Vnil (Vtail v1) (Vtail v2) (Vtail v3)) (lt_S_n H3)).
have [klen | ngtk] := (Compare_dec.le_lt_dec k (S n)).
rewrite (main k n n a b); intuition.
have : (k < S n)%nat; lia.
induction k0; intros; destruct n0.
VSntac v3; VSntac (Vtail v3); rewrite /=.
rewrite 2!Derive_deriveA_id 2!Vnth_tail.
rewrite (Vnth_eq v1 (kLess (S m) 0) (lt_n_S (kLess m 0))); try lia;
rewrite (Vnth_eq v2 (kLess (S m) 0) (lt_n_S (kLess m 0))) //; try lia.
VSntac v3; VSntac (Vtail v3); rewrite /=.
rewrite 2!Derive_deriveA_id 2!Vnth_tail.
rewrite (Vnth_eq v1 (kLess (S m) (S n0)) (lt_n_S (kLess m (S n0)))); try lia;
rewrite (Vnth_eq v2 (kLess (S m) (S n0)) (lt_n_S (kLess m (S n0)))) //; try lia.
inversion H0; inversion H1; try lia; subst; inversion H3; try lia.
have : (k0 <= S n0 <= S m)%nat; try lia. move => H4.
move: (IHk0 n0 m v1 v2 (Vtail v3) (lt_S_n H3) H4) => H5.
VSntac v3; rewrite /= H5 updateRnA_tail //; try lia.
Qed.
```